# How to set up loop in database until it connects to mysqlDB

Tags: mysql, go

I have init funcion in my golang program. I need to make it so the connection loops until it connects to database if it cant connect it idles then try's again and again for 60 seconds if it cant connect at end then it exist out. Also, have environment variable that overrides the default  60 seconds and user can put their own time for until it connects. I have my code below im looking and theres no solid solution in web .

```
var override string = os.Getenv("OVERRIDE")


func dsn() string {

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", username, password, ipdb, portdb, dbName)

func init() {

    var db, err = sql.Open("mysql", dsn())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Connection established to MYSQL server\n%s\n", dsn())
    }
    // Checking if table exists in database
    rows, table_check := db.Query("select * from " + "Url" + ";")

    if table_check == nil {
        fmt.Println("\nTable exists in the Database")

        count := 0
        for rows.Next() {
            count++
        }
        fmt.Printf("Number of records are %d \n", count)

    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\nTable does not exist in Database %s", table_check)
        _, status := db.Exec("CREATE TABLE Url (LongUrl varchar(255),ShortUrl varchar(32));")
        if status == nil {
            fmt.Println("\n New table created in the Database")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("\n The table was not created %s", status)
        }
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
func main(){
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch with a timer channel.

For every 500 ms the connection is attempted, and if in 60 seconds the switch has not been resolved then the timeout channel exits the loop.

For example:

```
func main() {
    doneCh := make(chan bool)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Could not open connection: %w", err)
        os.Exit(1) 
    }

    // Start polling for connection
    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(500 * time.Millisecond)
        timeoutTimer := time.After(time.Second * 60)
        for {
            select {
            case <-timeoutTimer:
                err = errors.New("connection to db timed out")
                doneCh <- true
                return
            case <-ticker.C:
                // Simulate some strange wait ... :)
                if rand.Intn(10) == 2 {
                    err = db.Ping()
                    if err == nil {
                        doneCh <- true
                        return
                    }
                }
                fmt.Println("Retrying connection ... ")
            }
        }
    }()

    // Start waiting for timeout or success
    fmt.Println("Waiting for DB connection ...")
    <-doneCh

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Could not connect to DB: %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Do some work
    fmt.Printf("Done! Do work now. %+v", db.Stats())
}
```

**Note**
Handle your errors as necessary. The `sql.Ping()` may return you some specific error which will indicate to you that you should retry.
Some errors may not be worth retrying with.

For timers and channels see:

- [Timers](https://gobyexample.com/timers)
- [Channels](https://gobyexample.com/channels)

**Edit: Supposedly simpler way without channels and using a while loop**

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Could not open connection: %w", err)
        os.Exit(1) 
    }

    defer db.Close()

    timeOut := time.Second * 60
    idleDuration := time.Millisecond * 500

    start := time.Now()
    for time.Since(start) < timeOut {
        if err = db.Ping(); err == nil {
            break
        }

        time.Sleep(idleDuration)
        fmt.Println("Retrying to connect ...")
    }

    if time.Since(start) > timeOut {
        fmt.Printf("Could not connect to DB, timeout after %s", timeOut)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Do some work
    fmt.Printf("Done! \nDo work now. %+v", db.Stats())
}
```

Comment: Is in there easier way and simpler way to do this?

Comment: What do you find hard in this example ? You could also do a while loop and check if some time has passed and break. I'll write example tomorrow.

Comment: @Tank92 Updated my answer with a simpler loop option